# Android insert data into mysql json

Tags: android, mysql, json

I'm trying to insert data into mysql using json here is my php code there is no problem but it insert query cannot work.JSON output always shows: `{"code":0}` it must be `{"code":1}` HELP

```
<?php

    header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $con = mysql_connect("xxxx","xxx","xxx");
    $db = mysql_select_db("android_data");

    $us = $_POST["uname"];
    $pa = $_POST["upass"];
    $pe = $_POST["uper"];

    $flag["code"] = 0;

    $sql = "insert into administrator (username,password,permission) values('".$us."','".$pa."','".$pe."')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($query)
    {
        $flag["code"] = 1;
        echo json_encode($flag);
        //echo $flag['StatusID'];
    }

    mysql_close($con);
    echo json_encode($flag);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO administrator (username, password, permission) VALUES( '$us', '$pa', '$pe' )");
```

One more thing to note, it looks like you are echoing the output twice for a successful query.

You might want to do something like this instead:

```
if ($query)
{
    $flag["code"] = 1;
    $flag["message"] = "success";
    echo json_encode($flag);


} else {
    // failed to insert row
   $flag["code"] = 0;
   $flag["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
   echo json_encode($flag);
}

 mysql_close($con);
```